# How do I pull down a remote branch?

Tags: git, git-pull

I've been searching for a half hour for how to do pull a remote branch, and cannot figure it out.

My remote git repository has a branch called `frontend`.  When I run `git pull origin frontend` I get the following output:

```
* branch             frontend     -> FETCH-HEAD
Already up-to-date.
```

When I run `git branch`, I get the following:

```
*master
```

Why isn't `frontend` in the list returned by `git branch`?

---

When I run `git branch -v -a`, one of the returned branches is `remotes/origins/frontend`...

Comment: The question in the title ("How do I pull down a remote branch?") is a separate question from the one in the body of the text ("Why isn't frontend in the list returned by git branch?").  When you did the `git pull` you did pull down the remote branch.  That relates to the question in the title.  There are any number of ways for you to create a local branch named "frontend" and some of those are described in answers below.  Those address the question in the body.

Answer (score 34):

`git pull origin frontend` is equivalent to `get fetch origin frontend` and `get merge frontend`. Note that this merges the remote branch named `frontend` to the current local branch, in your case `master`. If you want a local branch with the same name as the remote branch, you should create it first. One way to do this is

```
git checkout -b frontend
git pull origin frontend
```

You should read up on the differences between a local branch and a remote tracking branch.

Alternatively, you can manually fetch then checkout the branch:

```
git fetch origin
git checkout frontend
```

If you don't already have a branch with the name `frontend`, git will find the remote tracking branch and automatically create a local branch at the same commit.

Comment: There's one other subtle difference (that's gone in the newest git) when separating out the fetch-and-merge: when you run `git fetch <remote> <branch-list>`, older versions of git fetch all the named branches but put them *only* under the special name `FETCH_HEAD`, rather than updating your local copies of the remote's branches.  This means `git merge frontend` doesn't do what you wanted.  Newer versions update the "remote branches", so that the `git merge frontend` works as desired here.  My general rule is "avoid git pull" :-) which simply sidesteps the whole "which git version" question.

Answer (score 7):

You need to create local branch as well. Since there already is a remote branch in your repo, just type:

```
git checkout frontend
```

git will autocratically create local branch and set upstream branch as well.

Answer (score 5):

> Why isn't frontend in the list returned by git branch?

Because you don't have a local branch named "frontend".

There are a number of git config settings that might factor in here but one thing you can do if you want to create a local branch named "frontend" which tracks the remote branch of the same name is something like the following:

```
git branch --track frontend origin/frontend
```

I hope that helps.

Comment: This is the only one that worked for me